# Parse JSON objectAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm parsing a bunch of json objects from my API and place it into a table view. When I hit the a row I want it to parse an object from the API out of an array and forward it to another view so one can get more details.

If I place the code how I think it works in the cellForRowAtIndexPath everything is fine but by the time I place an NSLog in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and make him display the ID I parsed for the specific row I don't get anything?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *neuheitenCell = @"neuheitenCell";


    CJHomeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:neuheitenCell];

    sstring = [[idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ware_id"];
    //NSLog(@"Selected item with id: %@",sstring);

    return cell;

}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"stuff: %@", sstring);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Note the spelling.